# ios-charts Charts for Swift - purposely bleed/overflow chart bars

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using a Bar Chart that I'm trying to make look like a design. The design's bars overflow a bit at the bottom and have a transparency gradient on them. I can't find any property that you can use for this and I guess I'll have to override somewhere. I've also tried to draw layers on top of the graph at the bars positions/bounds without success.

I tried overriding the `BarChartRenderer` and change the Y-positions, but since the graph is supposed to be "scrollable" by default it clips the bar.
I've already disabled the scrolling/moving/zooming functions because I don't need them:

```
doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
highlightPerDragEnabled = false
highlightPerTapEnabled = false
clipValuesToContentEnabled = false
```

[image: graph - i want right]

Comment: can you share youre code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by drawing my own layers over the bars and then remove the old bars because of their anti-aliasing. This way it will be easier to implement the gradient too, and it works because you won't be able to move/scale the chart.

```
    let bottomY = self.contentRect.maxY - leftAxis.gridLineWidth
    for (_, bar) in self.barData!.dataSets.enumerated() {
        let layer = CALayer(),
        barBounds = self.getBarBounds(entry: bar.entryForIndex(0)! as! BarChartDataEntry),
        // 30 extra height at bottom
        frame = CGRect(x: barBounds.minX, y: barBounds.minY, width: barBounds.width, height: (bottomY - barBounds.minY) + 30)
        // Set the new frame size, Z position and background
        layer.frame = frame
        layer.zPosition = 10
        layer.backgroundColor = bar.color(atIndex: 0).cgColor
        // Add the new bar layer and remove old bar
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        bar.clear()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimum axis value so that it set the bottom line correct try this code as

```
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = __Your minimum bar value__ i.e. 17000 //that is mention in your above graph
```